# Why laravel 8 does not include custom env file

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I want to include a custom .env file in Laravel 8.75. To do this, I created a folder "site" for custom .env files (env files have name as domain).
I'm trying to include an env file with Dotenv::createImmutable (lib Dotenv v5.4.1) and with loadEnvironmentFrom
I do it in bootstrap/app.php or in AppServiceProvider files, but every time i get error "No application encryption key has been specified" as i dont have default .env

```
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])) {
           $host = idn_to_utf8($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 0, INTL_IDNA_VARIANT_UTS46);
           $envFile = sprintf('site/%s', $host); //define name custom .env
           if ($host && file_exists(sprintf('%s/%s', app()->basePath(), $envFile))) {
             app()->useEnvironmentPath(app()->basePath());
             app()->loadEnvironmentFrom($envFile);
             $detenv = Dotenv::createImmutable(app()->basePath(), app()->environmentFile());
             $detenv->load();
           }
```

After running this code variable $_ENV and app() has correct path and name of custom env file, but custom env file not connected and we have error "No application encryption key has been specified" in log file, as if we haven't default .env file

Answer (score 0):

Please try the command in the root

```
php artisan key:generate
```

and then the following command

```
php artisan config:cache
```

to clear and reset the config.

Comment: APP_KEY for custom .env file is the same as for default .env and key is correct and problem is not him. The application works correctly with this key in the default .env file.

Comment: The key error falls due to the fact that the application cannot find the custom .env file. I'm interested in the reason why app don't see the custom env

Comment: php artisan key:generate and php artisan config:cache  don't work